# How to schedule a DVB-T stream record for VLC?

Tags: vlc, streaming

I can watch TV with `vlc` (DVB-T). Timeshift and Record functions work fine. What could I do to schedule a stream record? I. e., ZDF today at 22:25 for 45 minutes.

This is my *channels.conf*:

```
Das Erste:618000000:INVERSION_AUTO:BANDWIDTH_8_MHZ:FEC_2_3:FEC_AUTO:QAM_64:TRANSMISSION_MODE_8K:GUARD_INTERVAL_1_4:HIERARCHY_NONE:1537:1538:96
ZDF:594000000:INVERSION_AUTO:BANDWIDTH_8_MHZ:FEC_2_3:FEC_AUTO:QAM_16:TRANSMISSION_MODE_8K:GUARD_INTERVAL_1_4:HIERARCHY_NONE:545:546:514
3sat:594000000:INVERSION_AUTO:BANDWIDTH_8_MHZ:FEC_2_3:FEC_AUTO:QAM_16:TRANSMISSION_MODE_8K:GUARD_INTERVAL_1_4:HIERARCHY_NONE:561:562:515
arte:618000000:INVERSION_AUTO:BANDWIDTH_8_MHZ:FEC_2_3:FEC_AUTO:QAM_64:TRANSMISSION_MODE_8K:GUARD_INTERVAL_1_4:HIERARCHY_NONE:33:34:2
MDR Sachsen:538000000:INVERSION_AUTO:BANDWIDTH_8_MHZ:FEC_2_3:FEC_AUTO:QAM_64:TRANSMISSION_MODE_8K:GUARD_INTERVAL_1_4:HIERARCHY_NONE:1553:1554:97
rbb Brandenburg:538000000:INVERSION_AUTO:BANDWIDTH_8_MHZ:FEC_2_3:FEC_AUTO:QAM_64:TRANSMISSION_MODE_8K:GUARD_INTERVAL_1_4:HIERARCHY_NONE:2833:2834:177
Bayerisches FS Nord:538000000:INVERSION_AUTO:BANDWIDTH_8_MHZ:FEC_2_3:FEC_AUTO:QAM_64:TRANSMISSION_MODE_8K:GUARD_INTERVAL_1_4:HIERARCHY_NONE:529:530:33
WDR Köln:538000000:INVERSION_AUTO:BANDWIDTH_8_MHZ:FEC_2_3:FEC_AUTO:QAM_64:TRANSMISSION_MODE_8K:GUARD_INTERVAL_1_4:HIERARCHY_NONE:4193:4194:262
Einsfestival:618000000:INVERSION_AUTO:BANDWIDTH_8_MHZ:FEC_2_3:FEC_AUTO:QAM_64:TRANSMISSION_MODE_8K:GUARD_INTERVAL_1_4:HIERARCHY_NONE:81:82:5
neo/KiKA:594000000:INVERSION_AUTO:BANDWIDTH_8_MHZ:FEC_2_3:FEC_AUTO:QAM_16:TRANSMISSION_MODE_8K:GUARD_INTERVAL_1_4:HIERARCHY_NONE:593:594:517
ZDFinfo:594000000:INVERSION_AUTO:BANDWIDTH_8_MHZ:FEC_2_3:FEC_AUTO:QAM_16:TRANSMISSION_MODE_8K:GUARD_INTERVAL_1_4:HIERARCHY_NONE:577:578:516
PHOENIX:618000000:INVERSION_AUTO:BANDWIDTH_8_MHZ:FEC_2_3:FEC_AUTO:QAM_64:TRANSMISSION_MODE_8K:GUARD_INTERVAL_1_4:HIERARCHY_NONE:49:50:3
```

I use VLC 2.0.1.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Faster than expected I found an answer! For this example I have to run:

```
echo 'cvlc dvb-t://frequency=594000000 :program=514 :run-time=2700 --sout Videos/Aufnahmen/heute-show-120330.mpg vlc://quit' | at 22:25
```

**What to adjust for other scheduled recordings:**

- `frequency`: this number after the channel-name in the *channels.conf*
- `program`: the last number of the line in the *channels.conf*
- `run-time`: for how long should be recorded (time in seconds)
- `sout`: place and filename for the output
- `at`: start time for the record