# Record TV program from VLC

Tags: vlc, tv, capture, dvb, video-recording

I am using VLC 2.0.1 to watch TV (DVB-T) through my PCI TV tuner

Is it possible to record a TV programm as an `.avi` or `.mp4` file? Can I record it with VLC or another app?

Comment: I think Kaffeine can do so, but I'm not 100% sure.

Answer (score 2):

The easiest way to record immediately is by pressing the **record button**:

[image]

To enable it click `View` → `Advanced Controls`.

Records become stored as **.ts** files which you can watch with VLC. You find them in ~/Downloads, which you can [change](https://askubuntu.com/q/122398/46531).

---

To cut .ts files I recommend **DVBcut** [image: Install dvbcut]: *DVBcut is a Qt application that allows you to select certain parts of an MPEG transport stream (as received via Digital Video Broadcasting, DVB) and save these parts into a single MPEG output file. It follows a 'keyhole surgery' approach where the input video and audio data is mostly kept unchanged, and only very few frames at the beginning and/or end of the selected range are re-encoded in order to obtain a valid MPEG file.*

By that tool you can **export the files to .mpeg** without worrying about any audio lag. Information about how to use it you find [on it's homepage](http://dvbcut.sourceforge.net/) (see [wiki question](https://askubuntu.com/a/10048/46531)).

---

To **record an mpeg-stream** use this **command** in a terminal:

```
cvlc dvb-t:// :dvb-frequency=$FREQUENCY :dvb-bandwidth=$BANDWIDTH :program=$PROGRAM :sout=~/Videos/record.mpg --no-sout-display
```

Take the parameters from your channels.conf, whereat `$PROGRAM` in each case is the last number of the line. If you want to watch your record at the same time replace the last parameter with `--sout-display`. To stop the record kill the process with <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>C</kbd> or close the terminal.

I tested to replace .mpg with .avi and .mp4 without success: One then has a shift of sound and the other doesn't record sound. But using .mpg seems to be an acceptable alternative to .ts.

You can **schedule records** as .mpeg-streams as described in [this post](https://askubuntu.com/q/117322/46531).

---

Another good alternative to watch TV on PC was **Me TV** [image: Install me-tv], but since a while it seems to be buggy and doesn't work as it should - which led me to use VLC, too.

Comment: jacob thank you for the respond
I knew it this method but it stores the records on .ts witch is not compatible with all players..
This is why i asked an app to save them to .avi or .mp4 :(

Comment: btw i also tried to convert .ts files to other formats with openshot but it had audio lag :(
I also tried MeTV to watch tv but i cant find channels. Vlc was the best solution for me :)

Comment: Just installed DVBcut but i am not sure i understand how it works.
I have a .ts file saved from vlc 
I must open this file with DVBcut and then what..?

Comment: no problem ;)
If i will find more infos ill post them 
Thank you

Comment: I added a link to dvbcut.sourceforge.net since it is explained there. If you should have serious problems, though, I would add a step-by-step guide to the wiki mentioned above. Just leave a comment.

Answer (score 2):

This may be a bit of an overkill, but **MythTV** is an absolutely incredibly awesome thing:

- you can tell it once you want to record a certain show and it will find it and record it automatically. Or to record all documentaries. Or to record a first episode of all soap operas.
- recorded episodes are neatly categorized in a nice UI
- you can tell it to keep only 10 latest episodes of a show
- you can tell it to find ad blocks so you can skip them (or maybe skip the movie and watch ads instead)
- it has a separate backend which runs in the background, so you don't have to manually start anything to record a program
- you can even set up your computer to wake up at night, record a show and shut down. Or you can have backend running on one machine which never shuts down and access it with multiple frontends installed on all your home PCs.
- you can set up access to your MythTV via a web browser so you can manage recordings over Internet

[image: MythTV]

There's a separate distribution of Ubuntu called [Mythbuntu](http://www.mythbuntu.org/) installing which would make sense if you're building a dedicated media center, but you can also install MythTV in "normal" Ubuntu

Comment: I think , mythtv is for online tv (?)
I want to use my pci tv tuner to watch tv .. is this possible with mythtv ?

Comment: MythTV is very much for recording programs with a TV tuner. It *may* have some online TV functionality (and also it can be used to manage other videos not recorded from TV), but definitely recording from TV is its main feature

Comment: And does it store streams in .avi or .mp4?

Comment: It stores streams in .mpg and .nuv formats. You can configure it to transcode the recordings into other formats. Or just use ffmpeg to transcode manually or via a script. However, I'm finding that I rarely need it

Comment: Sergey can i use MythTV to record a programm from vlc ?
Because i watch tv with my pci card from vlc

Comment: No, the idea is to use MythTV instead of VLC. You can watch live TV with MythTV too. With MythTV, you can start watching a show, then decide you want to record it in the middle of the show, press "record" - and the show will be recorded from the start

Answer (score 0):

**Tools > Preferences > Input & Codecs** look at **files** section for record directory.  I created a folder, but you need to at least your home directory.

When you are ready to record, you have to press <kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>R</kbd>. I mourn the loss of the red button, but you can look at the hotkeys section of preferences and see the record sequence.